# Codeigniter, Submit "button" missing instructions from controller or model?

Tags: php, codeigniter

the submit "button" isn´t working properly, I know there must be something missing, the problem is Idk what is it...
The main idea is to insert information, then do a refresh displaying it in a table below, all in the same "page", the "submit" doesn´t save :(.
Thanks in advance.

**Part of the code in Model:**

```
function create_gei()
{
 $data['theyear'] = $this->input->post('theyear');
 $data['qty_alumni'] = $this->input->post('qty_alumni');
 $data['emanations'] = $this->input->post('emanations');
 $data['temperature'] = $this->input->post('temperature');
 $this->db->insert("pdc_factor_gei", $data);
}
```

**Part of the code in Controller:**

```
function btn_create_gei()

   {
     $this->model_gas_consum->create_gei();
     $submit = $this->input->post('send');
     if($submit=='repeatgei')
    {
     redirect(current_url("gas_consum/factor_gei/"), 'refresh');
    }
     else
    {
     redirect("gas_consum/home_gas/");
    }
   }
```

**Part of the code in View "button":**

```
<?php echo form_open("gas_consum/factor_gei"); ?>

 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
   <button
   name="send" value="repeatgei" class="btn" type="submit">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Save</button>
 </div>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, change your

```
<button name="send" value="repeatgei" class="btn" type="submit">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Save</button>
```

To this

```
<?php echo form_submit('send', 'repeatgei', 'class="btn"'); ?>
```

Comment: @wolfan1983, should I replace the entire code for "this" or where it must go?

Comment: Weird, worked out of nowhere... well now the other issue is the cancel button, it should be the "else" but instead saves and redirects to another page. Any ideas how should it be?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="submit" name="send" value="repeatgei" class="btn">
```